# ASP.NET MVC4 - What is the actual data flow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I always hear and read that the flow of interactions in a ASP.NET MVC4 is that of Controller -> Model -> View.

But wouldn't it be accurate to say that this flow is actually the flow on a Http Get, and the flow on a Http Post is View -> Controller -> Model -> Controller -> View (same or different - doesn't matter)?

[image: HttpGet flow]

[image]

Comment: A bit unrelated, but don't forget about the 'Post/Redirect/Get' Pattern for a safe way to handle POSTs: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201104/Blog/ASP-NET-MVC-Post-Redirect-Get-Pattern/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are classifying as "View". In the case of the POST, there is no server side View code running at all, just browser side code. In the response flow there will be some view rendering done on the server into HTML for GET (and probably POST). It is this that I would say most people would be referring to when talking about the ASP.NET MVC flow.

Comment: Josh, thx for taking the time.  I think I understand what you mean.  Let me see if I can reword what you said with an example.  That "Submit" button, let's say, doesn't count as the View (browser side code) interacting with a Controller, that part is skipped.  Only when that post request hits the server, now it counts as the controller, taking in a request, doing whatever it needs to do, and returning some other view to the user. Is that pretty much what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean exactly.

Answer (score 0):

No. The view is an output-only medium which is rendered (usually to the HTTP response and sent to the client); it does not receive or react directly to any data sent to the server.

The diagram you have for "Http Get" is true for any HTTP request, regardless of the verb. First the request comes into the server where the routing engine decides where to send it - this will most likely be a Controller. Then the controller comes to life, invoking the Model Binder when necessary. This is responsible for the magic that happens behind the scenes where you can have a controller method `ActionResult Foo(MyComplexModel model)` and it assigns values from the request data to the parameters, also performing validation. Following this is the code in the controller, which most likely invokes a View, rendering it to the response stream.

Answer (score 0):

No, the diagram for POST is the same as GET.
When you are posting your form o doing a post vía Ajax, you are posting against a Controller's Action.

Comment: Actually you post to controller action the ViewModel on the View. I think that's the idea of the diagram...

Comment: @Bart - no.  You do not post the viewmodel, you post a collection of name-value pairs (if using standard data format), or possibly a blob of data (in the case of a file, or json data).  These may get mapped to a view model, or it may not.. but you are not actually posting an actual ViewModel itself.

Answer (score -1):

- The controller validates the request and call model for data
- Model do anything but validation input and control flow.
- Controller render the View or control application flow until end of
  flow
- View is rendered at end of application flow.

To mix HTTP flow with MVC, I think you can enumerate this way:

1. Http Get Request Controller validates input (route, parameters, etc)
2. Model do the 'application logic' like doing some algorithms, calling
   Db, etc. May need 'data modelation' like ViewModels  (ViewModel
   *might be* responsible for modeling the view)
3. Controller pick a particular view and ViewModel.
4. View is rendered and displayed to User. Client-side aka view logic
   can happen in the view like validating forms or doing more requests.
   (for the sake of simplicity I leave that out of the flow)

   Let's say I fill a form and submit
5. Http Post Request some data from the view.
6. Controller validate data, model do the business logic and controller
   redirect to Http Get (start again)

In summary, you end up serving Views on Get verb, submitting to controller for modifications on Post verb, and model do anything **but** input validation and flow control and eventually redirect to another Get verb.

This is only if you are using PRG pattern which is really really recommended as best practices.

Does this make sense to you ?

Comment: why the -1 ? I really appreciate a comment.